# Generic Methods passing subClass to baseClass defined Method?

Tags: c#, generics

QUESTION IS CLARIFIED
new thread : [subclass properties accessed in generic method with superclass input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18926597/subclass-properties-accessed-in-generic-method-with-superclass-input)

I have a base class A

subClasses B, C, and D inherit from A.

Each subClass has 3 subClasses a, b, and c.

a, b, and c have a list of unique properties.

However, now I want to build a generic function to access those properties, so how would I do this without switching on Type?

Clarification : I do not want a : B to have abstract C methods/properties

Example:

```
public void Method(A a){

if(a.isSubClassOf(B))

        {Console.WriteLine(a.BaProperty);}

if(a.isSubClassOf(C))

        {Console.WriteLine(a.CbProperty);}

if(a.isSubClassOf(D))

        {Console.WriteLine(a.DcProperty);}


}
```

Comment: To clarify, the properties would be of enum type, and all superClasses have a property of enum subType {B,C,D}

Comment: You should use `virtual` property in the `base class` and make it more specific in the `derived class`, of course the `Names` should be the same as in `base class`.

Comment: And when they're not the same name on the properties, you HAVE to switch types, such as `(a as B).BaProperty)`.  Or you could use dynamics, but that'll defeat the purpose of the class hierarchy.

Comment: I am hesitant to use virtual subTypes because I do not want all properties on all objects. In fact that was the whole point of using inheritance in my structure.

Comment: Eli, that may work, testing now...

Comment: Eli, Convert to answer? that worked perfectly and I would like to get some feedback on best practices :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't define a member in derived class and access it via the reference to base class without casting to derived class:

```
class A {}
class B
{
    public int i;
}

A a = new B();
a.i = 0; // error
((B)a).i = 0; // OK
```

Either declare virtual property in any of base types in your hierarchy, or use casting to the concrete derived type. Of course, in the second case your method doesn't make any sense.

Comment: a is already of class B. why would you cast ((B)a)? I see what you are saying though.

Comment: @CyberDefect: a typo, fixed.

Comment: Casting is going to have to be the way, for some reason it wasn't working last night... must have been tired.

Comment: @CyberDefect are your objects Proxies? Casting doesn't work when you have Proxies.

Comment: hrm, now its telling me that it is not an instance when I cast it... damnit

Answer (score 0):

Typically, you would use a `virtual` or `abstract` method defined in `A` and overridden in the subclasses.

```
public abstract class A
{
    protected abstract PropertyType PropertyValue {get;}

    public void Method()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(PropertyValue);
    }
}

public class B : A
{
    protected override PropertyType Property { get { return PropertyType.B; } }
}

// etc...
```

Comment: Unfortunately I do not want B properties in C subClasses though. Think along the lines of car : ford : vehicle and bycycle : schwinn : vehicle. Why does car have an abstract method to Pedal()?

Comment: @CyberDefect: you're misunderstanding OOP. `Car` shouldn't have a method `Pedal`, but `Vehicle` **must** have a method `Move`. How moving will be performed - this is an implementation detail.

Comment: ok, so my example was flawed in using Pedal. Think property FuelType. The point was that Ba and Cc share ONLY A properties. Casting is the answer.

Comment: @CyberDefect: Think carefully about your inheritance model.  What you want to do sounds like it will violate the Liskov Substitution Principle.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle

Answer (score 0):

An elegant solution is to override `ToString`

```
public abstract class A { }

public class B : A { 
    public int b { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return b.ToString();
    }
}

// Do the same with C and D ....


A[] array = new A[] { new B(), new C(), new D() };
foreach (A a in array) {
    Console.WriteLine(a);
}
```

Note that `Console.WriteLine` does not need to know about a special method or property in `A`. It also works for types not deriving from `A`.

Comment: Could you find any difference with virtual property, proposed earlier?

Comment: This works if the properties are of different type. It uses a method common to all types.

Comment: @CyberDefect If what Olivier suggests solves your problem, then use his implementation. Overriding the ToString method is a very standard procedure :P

Comment: I think I may have confused the issue by not posting a closer proxy to my actual problem. I think I will need to ask it in a better stated question :(

Answer (score 0):

It depends greatly in what you really want to achieve. In some cases what Steve Czetty suggests is the best option.

In others you could just keep all the properties different and have a virtual method in the base class that returns for example in this case a "string" that you can then write in the console or anything you wish.

**Edit**: You could override [ToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring.aspx) as Olivier suggested. But only if you feel what yo are going to retun is the "String representation of the object".

public abstract class A
        {
            public string PropertyA { get; set; }

```
        public virtual string GetString() //
        {
            return PropertyA;
        }
    }

    public class B:A
    {
        public string PropertyB { get; set; }
        public override string GetString()
        {
            return PropertyB;
        }
    }

    public class C:A
    {
        public string PropertyC { get; set; }
        public override string GetString()
        {
            return string.Format("{0} - {1}", base.GetString(), PropertyC) // for example if you wanted to do something more complex
        }
    }
```

Now if what you need can not be solved like this, you could cast as Dennis Suggested.

There is another posibility: you could use the visitor pattern. [Here](http://code.logos.com/blog/2010/03/the_visitor_pattern_and_dynamic_in_c_4.html) you can find several ways to implement it.

Just so you have an idea you would wind up having a class similar to this: (it will depend on what you really want to achieve)
You have to implement some other basic things (interface and some methods), but from a Reference to the base class you will be able to call the corresponding "Visit" method easily. There is a lot of detail in the link i added.

```
class ClassicVisitor : IAVisitor
    {

        public string SuperComplexStringResult { get;set; }

        public void Visit(B b) { SuperComplexStringResult = String.Format("Super Complex Stuff + {0}", b.PropertyB); }

        public void Visit(C c) { SuperComplexStringResult = String.Format("Super Complex Stuff + {0}", c.PropertyC); }
    }
```