# subclass properties accessed in generic method with superclass input

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance

I want to make an inventory/equipment system to interface with my item system. My item system is an inherited class system based around shared properties.

I store types in enums and give the items an enum value.

My inheritance structure:

```
Item {
  Equippable {
    Armor {Chest, Head}
    Weapon {Melee, Ranged}
  }
}
```

I have each subType define an enum variable in its parent class, so Chest would define the armorTypes enum in an explicit base constructor call with the type.

e.g.

```
public enum armorTypes {Chest, Helmet}

public class Armor : Equippable
{
    armorTypes armorType;

    public Armor(armorTypes at) : base(equippableTypes.Armor) 
    {
        armorType = at;
    }
}

public class Chest : Armor 
{
    int defense = 10;

    public Chest() : base(armorTypes.Chest) {}
}

public class Helmet : Armor 
{
    int defense = 5;

    public Helmet() : base(armorTypes.Helmet) {}
}
```

In my Inventory class I have blank versions of these items.

```
Inventory{
  public Chest chestSlot;
  public Helmet helmetSlot;
  public Melee meleeSlot;
  public Ranged rangedSlot;
}
```

I want to compare the objects in the two slots based on their properties.

```
void Compare(Item item) 
{
  switch((item as Armor).armorType)
  {
      case armorTypes.Chest :
        Console.WriteLine((item as Chest).defense + " or " + chestSlot.defense);
        break;
      case armorTypes.Helmet :
        Console.WriteLine((item as Helmet).defense + " or " + helmetSlot.defense);
        break;
  }
}
```

However, when I cast it using the as keyword, somehow I lose my instance?

Also, as I need to access item.armorType I cannot encapsulate Armor, can I?

Comment: there may be some typos, I did this on the fly...

Comment: I don't see any generics in your code. and java-like egyptian braces suck. don't use them please.

Comment: You are right, I am using the superClass type for all subclasses instead of using <T>... still pretty generic.

Comment: You: _However, when I cast it using the as keyword, somehow I lose my instance?_ Don't use `as` here. Cast with e.g. `((Helmet)item)`. If something goes wrong, it will give you a much better exception message, and you should understand the cause.

Comment: @CyberDefect: please, use tags carefully, because they're used for searching purposes. Your question really has nothing to generics, it is about OOP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how I'd implement this.
First of all, let the base class define basic comparison methods:

```
abstract class Item 
{
    // these methods define base comparison operations;
    // by default, items are not comparable;
    public virtual bool CanCompareWith(Item item)
    {
        return false;
    }

    // since we don't know all possible item properties,
    // this method hasn't implementation
    public abstract void CompareWith(Item item);
}
```

Next, we must define some default equipment. Armor:

```
abstract class Equippable : Item {}    

abstract class Armor : Equippable
{
    // every armor has a Defence property
    public abstract int Defence { get; }

    // the base comparison logic of two armors
    public override void CompareWith(Item item)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} or {1}", ((Armor)item).Defence, this.Defence);
    }
}

class Chest : Armor
{
    // if you want for chests to be comared with chests only:
    public override bool CanCompareWith(Item item)
    {
        return item is Chest;
    }

    public override int Defence
    {
        get { return 10; }
    }
}

class Helmet : Armor
{
    public override bool CanCompareWith(Item item)
    {
        return item is Helmet;
    }

    public override int Defence
    {
        get { return 5; }
    }
}
```

Weapon:

```
abstract class Weapon : Equippable
{
    // every weapon has Attack property
    public abstract int Attack { get; }

    // the base comparison logc of two weapons
    public override void CompareWith(Item item)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} or {1}", ((Weapon)item).Attack, this.Attack);
    }
}

class Melee : Weapon
{
    public override bool CanCompareWith(Item item)
    {
        return item is Melee;
    }

    public override int Attack
    {
        get { return 20; }
    }
}

class Ranged : Weapon
{
    public override bool CanCompareWith(Item item)
    {
        return item is Ranged;
    }

    public override int Attack
    {
        get { return 25; }
    }
}
```

Note, that there's no any enums here. This is because the type itself (e.g., `Chest`, `Helmet`, etc.) defines, where concrete item belongs to. Enum is just superfluous here.

Here's the inventory:

```
class Inventory
{
    // this is inventory storage;
    // collection allows the storage to be extended later, or be displayed at once
    // (e.g., some ShowAllInventory method)
    private readonly List<Item> inventoryItems;

    public Inventory()
    {
        inventoryItems = new List<Item>
        {
            // some predefined inventory slots with default inventory items
            new Chest(),
            new Helmet(),
            new Melee(),
            new Ranged()
        };
    }

    // these properties are required, if you want to access predefined 
    // inventory slots in strongly-typed manner; they are NOT required for comparison
    public Chest ChestSlot
    {
        get { return (Chest)inventoryItems[0]; }
        set { inventoryItems[0] = value; }
    }

    public Helmet HelmetSlot
    {
        get { return (Helmet)inventoryItems[1]; }
        set { inventoryItems[1] = value; }
    }

    public Melee MeleeSlot
    {
        get { return (Melee)inventoryItems[2]; }
        set { inventoryItems[2] = value; }
    }

    public Ranged RangedSlot
    {
        get { return (Ranged)inventoryItems[3]; }
        set { inventoryItems[3] = value; }
    }

    // The comparison.
    public void Compare(Item newItem)
    {
        foreach (var item in inventoryItems)
        {
            if (item.CanCompareWith(newItem))
            {
                item.CompareWith(newItem);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note, that internally inventory uses a collection to store its items. This allow to perform batch operations with items (like comparison, implemented in `Compare` method).

Now, let's define some new types of items and test our inventory:

```
class SuperHelmet : Helmet
{
    public override int Defence
    {
        get { return 50; }
    }
}

class SuperMelee : Melee
{
    public override int Attack
    {
        get { return 200; }
    }
}
```

The test:

```
        var inventory = new Inventory();
        var superHelmet = new SuperHelmet();
        var superMeele = new SuperMelee();

        inventory.Compare(superHelmet);
        inventory.Compare(superMeele);
```

Comment: Dennis, I see exactly what you mean about the enum, it was simply for Serializing in unity so I could create the prefabs.

The CanCompareWith idea is great, I will be using that for certain... I had been working on a similar concept, but I like you implementation much better.

The Item collection inventory system for batch operations is exactly what I had in mind.

Superb answer, much appreciated!